# Echo a string with a variable in it without expanding/evaluating it

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I've searched everywhere.  Tried echo and print.  Tried single and double quotes.  But I have parsed data and assigned it to a variable and would like to then evaluate it for if there is a variable within it.  I will then replace the variable with a wildcard and search for the file.

Example:

```
var="file.$DATE.txt"

### Where it goes wrong-  Needs to identify that $DATE is within the $var varaible.
test=$(echo "$var"|grep '\$')
if [[ $test ]]
then
    ### I would use whatever fix is discovered here as well
    test=$(echo $test|sed 's/\$[a-zA-Z]*/\*/')
fi

### (Actually pulling from remote machine to local)
cat $test > /tmp/temporary.file
```

Here is at least one of my many failures:

```
PROMPT> file=blah.$DATE
PROMPT> test=$(echo "$file"|grep '\$')
PROMPT> echo $test
PROMPT>
PROMPT>
```

I know it has something to do with expansion, but have no idea how to work it out.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you need solved? That var contain an un-expanded `$date`?. For that use: `var='file.$DATE.txt'`. To expand date when var is used? I am sure that you need to explain what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, to test if a variable is defined within the "var" variable.  Nested of sorts.

Comment: I found a way around my dilemma by immediately removing anything that appears to be a variable (without caring first that I need to) and swapping it with a wildcard:  `sed 's/\${*[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*}*/\*/'`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you need `$date` inside the variable var:

```
var='file.$date.txt'
```

That will keep the $ inside the variable:

```
$ echo "$var" | grep '\$'
file.$date.txt
```

Answer (score 17):

Use single quotes around variables to prevent shell expansion. Example `echo '$file'` will not expand `$file`.

Edit after comment below:

You can escape the `$` sign int the `var` variable with `var="file.\$DATE.txt"`.

Comment: I need it to expand, but only one level.  Forgot to add a step-by-step desired result.  But I would like the contents of $file to be evaluated for a dollar sign ($DATE).

Comment: Edited to solve that.

Comment: I receive that data from an outside source.  Even to replace the $ with a \$, I think, would require an echo.  HOWEVER, let me see if when I am parsing it I can squeeze it in.

Comment: Will work for this case/example too: `echo "/cpt_backup_a_\\`date +\%Y_\%m_\%d\\`.log"`. (see "`").